# How to prevent CEFSharp application from accessing widows resources

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have created wpf windows browser application using CEFSharp 69.0 and chromium version 3.3497.1841.0
It is working fine and able to access websites and popups also enabled.
This CEF Application is working in a secured environment access to system resources need to be blocked.
Please let me know is there any way to block accessing system windows resources from CEF web application.

For example some websites have a print button. On clicking that it will get navigated to system windows printer. 
Need a way to restrict this behavior.

please help me on this.

Comment: Too broad, please limit your question to a single specific topic. Windows resources could mean anything.

Comment: Need to disable  system print dialog appears on clicking print button on websites

Comment: That may not be possible without building CEF yourself.

Comment: It's a length process to build `CEF`, allocate a couple of days.

Comment: If i am building CEF. What all things need to get changed

Comment: You'll have to work that out for yourself.  The chromium dev google group might be able to provide some pointers.